# Simple calibration of probe

Tags: calibration

Usually I will calibrate passive oscilloscope probes under the scope setting with *"Start Attenuation/Offset Calibration"* and *"Start Skew Calibration"*. The last step is to ensure that the probe is fully compensated by the RC component in the probe.

I would like to understand the two types of calibration and RC (what they do and how they contribute to the accuracy of the probe). Right now, I am just clicking buttons on the scope without understanding the concepts.

I tried to read up on the articles but have yet to find. Can someone guide me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to add the scope model/make :) The scope comes with rather extensive documentation. Have you read it? If you have trouble understanding particular paragraphs in the manual, feel free to share the details - that way we'll be able to provide more targeted help I'd hope.